# Howto make twitter bootstrap compatible checkbox labels in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm trying to get two labels for one check box as described in Twitter Bootstrap's documentation. (see http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms --> horizontal forms --> checkbox (below text input))

So what I want to display is a label for the description on the left, the check box itself and a hint right next to it on the right.

The standard implementation of twitter bootstrap in simple_form gem creates a `<p>` tag for displaying the hint since it tries to be consistent for all kinds of inputs.

I now want to create a custom wrapper for "bootstrap checkboxes" in the simple_form initializer but I just cannot figure out how to solve this.

This is how I currently implemented it using bare rails (erb):

```
<div class="control-group">
 <%= f.label :recurring, :class => 'control-label' %>
 <div class="controls">
   <%= f.label :recurring, :class => 'checkbox' do %>
    <%= f.check_box :recurring %>
    <%= t('.recurring_hint') %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me or at least try to explain how these custom wrapper thing works? Thank you!

**Edit:** Let me ask my question more precisely: Can I use simple_form's wrappers API to use a label as a wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

1. Update to newest version of simple_form (2.0.2, had 2.0)
2. Override BooleanInput:

**app/inputs/boolean_input.rb**

```
class BooleanInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput
  def input
    if nested_boolean_style?
        template.label_tag(nil, :class => "checkbox") {
          build_check_box + inline_label
        }
    else
      build_check_box
    end
  end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

Call in template:

```
<%= f.input :recurring, :inline_label => t('.recurring_hint') %>
```

Comment: I successfully implemented the inline checkboxes using simple_form 2.1 and `config.wrapper_mappings` feature, example of the implementation in the following commit: 

https://github.com/amooma/GS5/commit/7d507dcc1bbbf5244b8d75f40c7cb6bc15906b33

Answer (score 1):

With [latest simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), the option is available out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can install simple_form with bootstrap suport, so you don't need to write the wrappers like control-groups, etc.

Check this link on installation:
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#twitter-bootstrap

What you need to do is just run the command:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

In this page you can see some examples, including horizontal checkboxes with bootstrap and simple_form: http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/articles/new

If you really want to use it the way you are doing, you need to add the class "inline" along with the "checkbox" on the label.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already installed the Bootstrap support for simple_form - forgot to mention it. Most things work well with it but the hints for checkboxes are wrapped with a <p> tag instead of a label with the input itself.